# OnLongClickListener is not working as it's supposed to work

Tags: android, view, oncreate, onlongclicklistener, android-toast

The code is very simple.. Nothing great I am just trying to toast a message and for some reason the behavior is different in two cases.

Case 1 : This is working:

Here's the code:

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.webopen);


            TextView sometext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.click);
            sometext.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Long click Working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return false;
                }
            });


            }
```

Case 2: Not working! I want to know the reason why it's not working

```
public class OnClick extends Activity implements OnLongClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webopen);

        TextView sometext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.click);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.click:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Long click enabled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // OR
            // Something();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public boolean Something() {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Long click enabled",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
}
```

There's nothing great about the code but I just want to know the reason for onLongClickListener not working.

Any suggestions will help ..:)

Comment: u miss someText.setOnLongClickListener(this);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting the `onLongClickListener` for `someText`. You need to add this:

```
someText.setOnLongClickListener(this);
```

This line will attach the listener object to the `TextView` Object. In the first case, you make the call to `setOnLongClickListener`, which is why it works. In this instance, you are creating a new `onLongClickListener` object *in-line*.

In the second example, your `Activity` is inheriting `OnLongClickListener`, which makes it an instance of that object. So to set the listener for `someText`, pass the listener `this`, which is a reference to the current class.

Comment: Thanks.. I totally forgot about regestering the onLongClickListener to my textview.. I changed my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Case 2 missing `setOnLongClickListener` for `sometext`.

```
TextView sometext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.click);  
sometext.setOnLongClickListener(this); // missing
```

In the first case you used a annonymous inner class.

In the second your class implements the interface `OnLongClickListener`

Answer (score 2):

You don't register a `onLongClick` listener for the `TextView`.
Add the following line in your codes `onCreate` and it should work.

```
sometext.setOnLongClickListener(this);
```